# Cloudflare Pages Functions context.data

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-pages

I would like to pass data from my Cloudflare Functions middleware to my Cloudflare Function.  I suspect I can do this using context.data.  However, [the documentation in Cloudflare](https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/platform/functions/api-reference/#data) does not specify what this field is.  Has anyone got any ideas what this field is and how it is supposed to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer on Cloudflare:

"It’s an arbitrary object you can attach data to that will persist during the request. The most common use-cases are for middleware that handles auth and may need to set context.data.username or similar."

Ref: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/what-is-context-data-in-pages-functions/476559/2?u=safa

More Notes:
To use context.data make sure that you do not replace it:

```
context.data = "some value";
```

Instead you should add a property like so:

```
context.data.myprop = "some value";
```

If you do not do this data will not be persisted.